# Django http-request in graphene schema

Tags: django, request, schema, django-sessions, graphene-python

How do I get the http-request-session object into a graphene schema?

I have stored som values in request session that I need access thru. A possible solution is to send the session-id to the frontend and then pass it into the post request, but that does not seem like a good solution.

Graphene hast a context_value but I don't understand how I works.

Into my Django-views I put this:

```
schema = graphene.Schema()
schema.execute('{ viewer }', context_value={'session': request.session})
```

In my graphene schema if I try to do like described in the tutorial(https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/docs/execution/execute.rst), it says

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  viewer = graphene.Field(Viewer)

  def resolve_viewer(self, info):
    info.context.get('session')
    print(info.context.session.keys()) #an empty array
    return Viewer()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access a [Django session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) in a resolve method with `info.context.session`

For example

```
print("session:", info.context.session)
print("keys:", info.context.session.keys())
```

in a resolver outputs for me

```
session: <django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7fa98e6ddac8>
keys: dict_keys(['_auth_user_id', '_auth_user_backend', '_auth_user_hash'])
```

Some things that you can check to debug:

1. make sure the session middleware is configured
2. if you're constructing a `schema` object in Django, the format you want is `result = schema.execute(query, context_value=request)` -- for more details see my answer at [GraphQL queries in Django returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918978/graphql-queries-in-django-returning-none/49924807#49924807)

Comment: I don't know why but it works without any change after I used the print session. Thank you for your answer.